# Jquery Datatables and MVC Form Post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I have a table (list of items) within a form that allows the user to do some action on each row (ex: delete an item).  When the user clicks submit, all the rows (data and action) are sent to the controller.  Works great.

Now I want to add some datatables filter functionality to the table.  I get it to work just fine on the View but when I click Submit, all it sends is a null value instead of the row data.  My understanding is that datatables modifies the page/DOM and somehow I need to get it back onto the page before the submit fires.  I saw some suggestions to use the datatables API function fnGetHiddenNodes() but I wasn't sure how to do this on my page.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Code**

```
@model IEnumerable<Admin.Models.MemberFeedback>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Member Feedback";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatables")

   @using (Html.BeginForm("MemberFeedback", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "processmemberfeedback" }))
    {
        <table class="dynamicTable table table-striped table-bordered table-primary" id="feedbackemails">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>Feedback</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @Html.EditorForModel()
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit1" class="btn btn-inverse"/>
    }
</div>

<script>
    /* Table initialisation */
    var oJobListingsTable = $('#feedbackemails').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": "No records found.",
            "sLengthMenu": "Rows: _MENU_",
            "sSearch": "Filter: "
        },
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
    });
</script>
```

How do I get a jquery datatables form to post back correctly to the Controller (and not send a null value)?

**Update 8-29-13**

I am following abc123's suggestion and I can get it to serialize a string in the hidden field.  However, I still can't get that to post back to my controller.  I've tried the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MemberFeedback(IEnumerable<MemberFeedback> memberfeedbacks, string dataTableFiltered)
{ ...}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MemberFeedback(string dataTableFiltered)
{ ...}
```

but both of these give me a null value for dataTableFiltered.  I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here.

Comment: show code or it didn't happen, also recommend using http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @MikeSmith Have u  found a solution to this issue? I also face same problem and question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404587/mvc3-model-is-null-if-datatable-filtering-is-applied

Comment: @Jmat I don't think I ever found a way around it.  My recollection is that we just didn't use filtering on that particular datatable.  Sorry for not being much help

Answer (score 0):

### jQuery DataTables 1.9 and Above

***Links used***

1. [DataTables Example for Form Submission](http://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html)
2. [How to get filtered Data](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/214/how-to-get-searched-or-filtered-data/p1)
3. [JSON2 array serializing](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

**Code:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Admin.Models.MemberFeedback>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Member Feedback";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatables")

   @using (Html.BeginForm("MemberFeedback", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "processmemberfeedback" }))
    {
        <table class="dynamicTable table table-striped table-bordered table-primary" id="feedbackemails">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>Feedback</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @Html.EditorForModel()
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <br />
        <input type="hidden" id="dataTableFiltered">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit1" class="btn btn-inverse"/>
    }
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#MemberFeedback').submit( function() {
        $('#dataTableFiltered').val(JSON.stringify(oTable._('tr', {"filter":"applied"})));
    });

    /* Table initialisation */
    var oJobListingsTable = $('#feedbackemails').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": "No records found.",
            "sLengthMenu": "Rows: _MENU_",
            "sSearch": "Filter: "
        },
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
    });
</script>
```

**Description**

```
oTable._('tr', {"filter":"applied"})
```

Returns the data from the data table with filters applied.

```
JSON.stringify(oTable._('tr', {"filter":"applied"}))
```

Returns the JSON string of the above.

```
$('#dataTableFiltered').val(JSON.stringify(oTable._('tr', {"filter":"applied"})));
```

Sets the value of the `dataTableFiltered` hidden input to the above.

***Note: this uses the [JSON2.js plugin](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)***

Comment: I follow your solution and see that the serialize string is in the dataTableFiltered hidden field.  Can you help me understand how to get that to post back to the Controller?

Comment: @MikeSmith That should just happen, if you have the field in your model.  Since you are submitting it and it is in an input.  Just need to have the model capture the info :)

Comment: Drat.  Still not working.  Added some code above to show what my controller looks like.

Comment: @MikeSmith install [fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/) then click submit and watch what data is posted to what URL...this is the easiest method of seeing where the disconnect is.  also I meant add a string to `MemberFeedback` and then it will just add it to that model on return.  in the view make the value of the input `@MemberFeedback.stringName`

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#frmInventario').submit(function () {
                debugger;
               var oTable =  $('#TableId').dataTable();
                oTable.fnFilter("");
                var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
                oSettings._iDisplayLength = -1;
                oTable.fnDraw();


            });
```